# How to remove google web app from workspace marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am currently building a web app for my company. I am trying to get the web app listed in Google Marketplace. I made a mistake in the initial listing to make it public when I should have made it private. I need to know:-

1. How do I make my listing private when they are public.
2. If point one cannot be done. how do I remove my app from the listing completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/manage-app-listing#unpublish_your_app_listing

Essentially you use the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK to both publish and unpublish your Apps